# Automated mouse click from a background thread

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates

I'm having a problem automating a mouse click from a background thread.

Currently, I have a background thread which is continuously gathering a lists of points to click within specific windows.

When these points are supposed to be clicked I call a method to click at these points. As soon as I attempt to iterate the list from this background thread it restarts the background method.

I have implemented a delegate in order to run the clicking method on the main thread. This allows me to iterate the list. When I debug/break point the method that clicks the position it hits as it should. Although when I do not have a break point it seems to fail to run the method. I have put delays above the `ClickOnPoint` to show the mouse movements but the mouse position doesn't change.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Am I using delegates correctly? Should I be calling `InvokeRequired` on the form or somewhere else?

**Delegate Definition:**

```
delegate void ClickPositionsCallback(IntPtr handle, int position, Dictionary<int,Rectangle> positions);
```

**Calling From Background Thread:**

```
this.ClickPositions(kvp.Key, position.Key, positions);
```

**Method that checks if invoke required**

```
private void ClickPositions(IntPtr handle,int position,Dictionary<int,Rectangle> positions)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        ClickPositionsCallback = new ClickPositionsCallback(ClickPositions);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { handle,position,positions });
    }
    else
    {
        this.clickPositions(handle, position, positions);
    }
}
```

**Method that iterates list and performs clicks:**

```
private void clickPositions(IntPtr intPtr, int position,Dictionary<int, Rectangle> positions )
{
    SetForegroundWindow(intPtr);
    List<Point> Points = new List<Point>();
    lock (positions)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < positions.Count; i++)
        {
            Points.Add(new Point(positions[((position + i) % 6)+1].Left + positions[((position + i )% 6) + 1].Width / 2, positions[((position + i) % 6) + 1].Top + positions[((position + i) % 6) + 1].Height / 2));
        }
    }
    var oldPos = Cursor.Position;
    foreach (Point p in Points)
    {
        ClickOnPoint(intPtr, p);
    }
    Cursor.Position = oldPos; 
}
```

**ClickOnPoint method**

```
private void ClickOnPoint(IntPtr wndHandle, Point clientPoint)
    {
            /// get screen coordinates
            ClientToScreen(wndHandle, ref clientPoint);
            /// set cursor on coords, and press mouse
            Cursor.Position = new Point(clientPoint.X, clientPoint.Y - SystemInformation.CaptionHeight);
            mouse_event(0x00000002, 0, 0, 0, UIntPtr.Zero); // left mouse button down            
            mouse_event(0x00000004, 0, 0, 0, UIntPtr.Zero); // left mouse button up
    }
```

Comment: You missed the definition of `ClickOnPoint` method. Nothing seems wrong with your code you posted. Post the code for that method please.

Comment: I have updated the code to include ClickOnPoint method.

Comment: Do you lock on `positions` inside the background thread also? Since you're calling `Invoke`, if `positions` is already being locked, it will result in a deadlock.

Comment: No I only lock positions as shown in the code example.